# Unknown column 'Time' in 'order clause'

Tags: sql, post, typed-arrays

I am trying to fill a form with data from a table and then edit/update it but get this error - please help.

SQL query:

```
UPDATE  `table_name` SET  `Time` =  `$_POST[submit_time]` ,
`Form` =  `$_POST[form_name]` ,
`Field` =  `$_POST[field_name]` ,
`Value` =  `$_POST[field_value]` ,
`Order` =  `$_POST[field_order]` ,
`File` =  `$_POST[file]` WHERE  `Time` =  `$_POST[hidden]` ;
```

MySQL said:

> 1054 - Unknown column 'Time' in 'where clause'

Comment: Could you show please structure of your table?

Answer (score 0):

This simply means that you do not have a column called `Time` in your table `table_name`

To troubleshoot, you should run `DESC table_name;`. This shows up all the columns in `table_name`  table.

You should be able to figure out the correct spelling or correct column name for the time part storage as the error, suggests that there is no `time` column.